# Image compression in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

My website takes too much time to display the content. Maximum sec taken for loading the image. so for that is there any way to compress it or else is there any other option to solve it ?.

Comment: Have you tried [ngx-image-compress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress) ?

Answer (score 0):

there is gulp plugin imagemin for that (can save around 10% maybe). Another options: use svg (vector images) or graphic font like font-awesome instead of raster image.

Suggestion: make sure that the cause is really the image. Maybe code itself is too big (remove unused modules, webpack-analyzer-plugin can be helpful) or slow (first of all compile in AOT mode, not JIT)

Answer (score 0):

I think image compression alone will not take you far enough. Lazy loading your images will have a huge performance impact on your website, you can do so using the new [intersection observer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) API which requires a [polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill) as its not supported in all browsers. This article by [angularindepth](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-modern-solution-to-lazy-loading-using-intersection-observer-9280c149bbc) goes through the process of creating such a directive.

To see how much performance you can squeeze out lazy loading image, try auditing your page using the lighthouse tool in the chrome devtools.